# How can I make IF loop dynamic without adding condition for every element in the array?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link in HTML which passes index to JS. In JS I am getting the index and based on the index I am trying to add some styling and functionality. I am now using hardcoded index values, as I know the index is limited to 5.
But, now this is dynamic and I don't know how many items will be in the array. Now, I am trying to make the code dynamic so, I don't have to worry about how many items are in the array.

My code:

```js
tPositions = [0, 1, 2, 3];
gotoSlide(i) {
    if (index == 0) {
      this.setSlide = 'translateX(-' + this.tPositions[index] + '%)';
    } else if (index == 1) {
      this.setSlide = 'translateX(-' + this.tPositions[index] + '%)';
    } else if (index == 2) {
      this.setSlide = 'translateX(-' + this.tPositions[index] + '%)';
    } else if (index == 3) {
      this.setSlide = 'translateX(-' + this.tPositions[index] + '%)';
    }
```

```html
<a *ngFor="let items in tPositions; let i = index" gotoSlide(i)>{{items}}</a>
```

Comment: The lines are all the same. If your current code works, and `index` will always be within the range, just replace the whole function with `this.setSlide = 'translateX(-' + this.tPositions[index] + '%)';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine how many items are in the array with `array.length`.

This answer assumes that there is an array called `slides` which contains the slides.

```
function goToSlide (i) {
  this.setSlide = `translateX(-${i}%)`;
}
```

```
<a *ngFor="let slide in slides; let i = index" gotoSlide(i)>{{ slide }}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered counting the number of items in your array and make a for loop based on that i variable?